# Is python len function on set thread safe?

Tags: python

Python 2.7. Set imported using "import sets"

Is it safe for one thread to fill the set with objects using the add function and another thread to wait until the set has reached a required size by calling the len function on the set. No protection is in place.

EDIT: "until the set has reached at least a specified size"

Comment: Safe? Yes, should be. Smart? Probably not

Comment: If you want the other thread to run when the set has accumulated an exact count of items, then it's not even safe.

Comment: Please take a look at [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) if you haven't. I consider GIL a must-read before attempting to write threaded codes in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`len()` is read-only so I'm not sure what you mean by thread-safe. It will not make your program crash if the set is being updated by a different thread, at least.

If you are waiting for a set to reach N items, before you start doing something in the thread, you might end up with >N items, since by the time you start your work, new items might have been added. No guarantees there, obviously.

Also, if you are removing things from the set in the second thread, you don't have any guarantee that you have N items, even if that's what `len()` returned.

Finally, if you want to post a new question describing which problem you are trying to solve using this pattern you might get more constructive answers.

Comment: I'm trying to track down a difficult issue and am grasping at straws but the answers given here are reassurance enough that this is not the issue. If I add too much context to my questions then it will be removed.

Comment: Ignore the above comment. I've made an edit clarifying and  you have answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: I see. Debugging concurrent programs is difficult. I'm assuming you are getting some kind of error or strange behavior, try adding some `assert` statements for constraints that you believe should always hold, such as `assert len(my_set) >= N`, or similar. This way, at least your program will fail early, making the error easier to find.